# Android 3D animation

Tags: android, 3d

I have been working on Android for a few months. Now i want to jump to gaming in Android. So are there any resources, ebooks, or tutorial where I can study game development be it 2D or 3D.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a long and not easy road. Start from 2D graphics by making some simple animations on images, try making a simple game. Check API for 2D and 3D graphics .

Here're some useful links

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development

http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/4160/developing_games_for_android.php

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

http://androidforums.com/android-games/

http://www.joystiq.com/2007/11/06/cell-developer-talks-google-android-gaming-possibilities/

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/1_X/

**UPDATE**

A good getting started guide

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development

Here're some good tutorials

http://www.quesucede.com/page/show/id/conway_game_of_life_android

**P.S.** Start from small things!

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks ........
I have bookmarked the links, also i am searching for some ebook or tutorial where they start on with small small code like the first link that you have posted. Well the search still continues .......

Comment: @ WarrenFaith - O ya, i have already read and compiled all the parts of the 2D one, all those are great, continue the good work. 

Thanks.